# How do i bring text in UITextView inwards from both sides and from above?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I want my UITextView to show text but not have the text be as wide as the screen. The problem I face with this, however, is that I want the scrollbar to be in the position it's in now. I'm unsure how to do this. Here's an image of the text i want bringing in, to show you what i mean a bit more clearly:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the position of the text using the `contentInset`, `contentOffset` and `contentSize` properties of `UIScrollView` (which is the superclass of `UITextView`).